# Do I need a transit visa at Istanbul Airport to visit the city?

Tags: visas, transit, isl, bangladeshi-citizens

Do I need a transit visa at Istanbul Airport to visit the city of Istanbul.  I am a Bangladeshi citizen and booked Turkish Airline flight to Russia. Transit period 12 hours in Istanbul.
If need transit visa, then how much does it cost?

Comment: "Dolor" means sorrow. I don't know how much sorrow a Turkish visa would cause you but I've edited the question. :-)

Comment: Do you wish to leave the terminal to do some sightseeing? If so then this question is a duplicate of the one pointed to by @KateGregory.

Answer (score 1):

You will only need a visa if you plan to visit Istanbul. If you are staying in the transit area, then you do not need a visa. From the Turkish [Ministry of Foreign Affairs FAQ Page](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa):

> Question: I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will
>   land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I
>   need to get transit visa?
>
> Answer: If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you
>   are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make
>   visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation. Contact
>   information of the said missions can be reached through www.mfa.gov.tr
>   (Ministry/Turkish Representations).

However, if you want to visit Istanbul, then you [will need a visa](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> Bangladeshi nationals holding diplomatic and official/service passport
>   are exempted from visa for their travels up to 90 days. **Ordinary
>   passport holders are required to have visa.** These passport holders
>   with a valid Schengen or OECD member's visa or residence permit may
>   get their single entry e-Visas valid for one month e-Visas via the
>   website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they meet certain conditions.